# How to export data into a prn file (fixed width with space fill) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixed-length-record

I did not see this kind of task done anywhere and was wondering how I could export data in a `.prn` file format in RoR.

The idea would be to have:

- field 1 -> length: 6 chars -> content: "blah"
- field 2 -> length: 8 chars -> content: "foo"
- field 3 -> length: 4 chars -> content: "bar"

and convert it to a line which would be like:

```
"blah  foo     bar " -> total 18 chars
```

I need this because the ERP I'm using only accept fixed width data field.

Comment: it's not showing but it would be 2 spaces after "blah" and 5 spaces after "foo" in the resulting line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While both your answers are good, I also found the ruby function [ljust()](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000813):

I then have:

```
"blah".ljust(6)+"foo".ljust(8)+"bar".ljust(4)
```

Hope it helps anyone needing the same thing...

Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 3):

Look at Array#pack:

```
a = %w(blah foo bar)
a.pack("A6A8A4")
=> "blah  foo     bar "
```

Comment: Definitely the most concise approach. May be hard on the eyes, but character-count is hard to beat.

Answer (score 1):

I am no Ruby expert, but at the very least, there is [sprintf](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005962):

```
C:\Temp> ruby -le "printf '[%-6s%-8s%-4s]', 'blah', 'foo', 'bar'"
[blah  foo     bar ]
 |•••••|•••••••|•••
```